# Why is there random choice made in a 2 node + file share cluster when File share dies?

Tags: windows, cluster, windows-cluster, windows-server-2022

In a 2 node wsfc with file share witness, each node has got 1 vote, and the witness also has got 1 vote. Total 3 votes.

Given that we have concepts of dynamic quorum, dynamic witness; when the file share dies (that is - either the connectivity to the file share is down or the file share server crashes), why does windows assign the voting power randomly to one of the 2 nodes?

Therefore, if the voting power is with the passive node, then if the active node crashes, the cluster will go offline.

Why doesn't it assign the voting power to only the primary node? Therefore, if active node crashes then cluster will go offline, but if passive node crashes then the cluster will remain up.

Comment: `Therefore, if active node crashes then cluster will go offline` if that is the case, that is what you should lead with. Also, "file share dies" is something you should elaborate on, as shares typically don't "die".

Comment: 1. What do you mean by that is what I should lead with please?

Comment: 2. File share dies means either the connectivity to the file share is down or the file share server crashes.

Comment: It is odd that a legacy active passive cluster does not fail over to the passive node when the active node is unavailable. Have you checked the cluster log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic quorum mechanism doesn't know about your service and on which node it is active. It is designed to work with Windows Server roles and Hyper-V VMs. Hyper-V VMs can run on multiple nodes at the same time. If you look at MS guides, it states that there is a 50 percent chance to survive a second server failure (second voter failure). That's exactly what you see, if node with 2 vote survives, your cluster will survive. Might help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/understand-failover-cluster-quorum

Comment: Thank you, the answer and links are really helpful.

Comment: The star wind link says `The majority of vote is 2 votes. So a two nodes cluster as above is not really resilient because if you lose a node, the cluster is down.` in the first example. I believe this is wrong as there is 50% chance that the cluster will not go offline. Am I right?

Comment: The starwind article doesn't have any mention of the fact that the last standing node has a 50% chance of survival.

Comment: I would recommend to follow the official docs. From my experience there is indeed 50% chance for a survival of a second failure in a 2 node cluster.